# Add "Togglz" feature toggle library to Spring Boot REST API

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, togglz, featuretoggle

I'm trying to use the **Togglz** library which allows you to wrap your application logic and be able to toggle it ON or OFF, with some advanced strategies. I am going through the Spring Boot documentation for it, and although its quite concise, I'm finding it missing pieces of information that are not allowing me to test this properly.

***reference:***
https://www.togglz.org/documentation/spring-boot-starter.html

1. I am running a **Spring Boot 2.4.5** version project and this documentation says to import the dependency, which I did:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.togglz</groupId>
  <artifactId>togglz-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

2. The documentation then states you can use an auto-configuration class on your **@RestController**, like

```
@Controller
public class MyClass {
  private FeatureManager manager;

  public MyClass(FeatureManager manager) {
      this.manager = manager;
  }

  @RequestMapping("/")
  public ResponseEntity<?> index() {
      if (manager.isActive(HELLO_WORLD)) {
           ...
      }
  }
}
```

Here is already where I had some questions that I didn't see explained, first, that are passing a enum "HELLO_WORLD" as an argument to this `isActive()` function on the FeatureManager. I don't see how they are injecting this into the method/class. They do show how to declare the feature ENUM in the yaml, though, this is not referencing the "HELLO_WORLD" that was passed into the isActive() method mentioned previously, i.e. :

```
togglz:
  features:
    FOO:
      enabled: true
    BAR:
      enabled: false
```

Further down the documentation, they finally do reference this `HELLO_WORLD` enum, but I tried adding this to my application.yaml and I can't seem to figure out how they are injecting these Feature Enums into these methods:

```
togglz:
  enabled: true # Enable Togglz for the application.
  features: # The feature states. Only needed if feature states are stored in application properties.
    HELLO_WORLD:
      enabled: true
```

The documentation does explain how to create an enum class for these features, ***but they explictly list it as an alternative to defining it in the yaml file***

```
public enum MyFeatures implements Feature {

    @EnabledByDefault
    @Label("First Feature")
    FEATURE_ONE,

    @Label("Second Feature")
    FEATURE_TWO;
}

@Bean
public FeatureProvider featureProvider() {
    return new EnumBasedFeatureProvider(MyFeatures.class);
}
```

I tried this also, and I just got more Bean exception errors when I try to run the Application, i.e.

```
Description:

Parameter 2 of method featureManager in org.togglz.spring.boot.autoconfigure.TogglzAutoConfiguration$FeatureManagerConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.togglz.core.user.UserProvider' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.togglz.core.user.UserProvider' in your configuration.
```

***Can anyone who has successful used this library provide input how to set a simple feature toggl***e ? Ultimately, I want to be able turn ON/OFF this feature while the application using a **RELEASE DATE** *activation* strategy i.e. `2021-06-30 00:00:00` such that I can have the toggle activate based on a datetime.

reference: https://www.togglz.org/documentation/activation-strategies.html

Can this be done in the yaml?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use an Enum you will have to inject the `FeatureProvider` that was auto-configured and call `featureProvider.getFeatures()` to get hold of all available features.
You can then check their state with the `FeatureManager`.
I agree that this is not obvious from the documentation.

It should be possible to configure the activation strategy via your `application.yml` too.
See the example section "Application Properties" at the very end of https://www.togglz.org/documentation/spring-boot-starter.html.
It should look like this:

```
togglz.features.FOO:
  enabled: true
  strategy: release-date
  param:
    date: ..
    time: ..
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Implemented the library successfully only change required in the above mentioned code or for the exception required a bean of type `org.togglz.core.user.UserProvider` that could not be found is to add one more bean UserProvider.

```
@Bean
public UserProvider getUserProvider() {
    return new ServletUserProvider("admin");
}
```